# Dynamically generated insert and select statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, information-schema

I have a database with some tables in it and I want to make dynamically generated **insert** and **select** statements without the need to use the case statement in the select clause for each table.

The select statement is quite easy, the challenge is with the insert one because I have to deal with each column and its data type. I managed to overcome it by means of a case statement, but I think it's hard working for tables with lots of columns and for databases with many tables.

I wish it was possible to change hardcoded table and column names for each table and column I need the dynamically generated SQL command.

I worked out in the following select statement for the given tables of the database (testDB) I have:

```cs
use testDB;

go

set dateformat dmy;

select
    'select * from ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ';' as cmd_select,
    'insert into ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ' (' +
    stuff(( select ', ' + column_name
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = t.name and ordinal_position > 1
            order by ordinal_position
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        1, 2, '')
        + ') values (' + 
    case t.name
        when 'Person' then '''xxx'''
        when 'WeightHistory' then '0.0, ''' + convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 103) + ''', ''' + left(convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 108), 5) + ''', 1'
        when 'WorkTime' then '''' + convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 103) + ''', ''' + left(convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 108), 5) + ''', 1, null'
        when 'TimeReference' then '''07:00'', ''' + convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 103) + ''', null'
    end
     + ');'as cmd_insert --,
    --t.lob_data_space_id
    --, s.name, t.name, *
from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.schemas as s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.lob_data_space_id = 0; /* tables that don't have LOB columns (sysdiagrams, varchar(max), xml, etc.) */
```

**What exactly I want to know is:**
Is there a better way of making the dynamically generated insert statement without using a case statement for each table and column of the database?

**ADITIONAL INFO**

The table definition for the above code is the following:

```cs
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where lower(name) = N'person' )
    begin
        create table Person.Person (
            PersonID int
                            constraint PK_Person
                            primary key
                            identity (1, 1),
            Name varchar(100)
        );
    end;
go
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where lower(name) = N'weighthistory' )
    begin
        create table dbo.WeightHistory (
            WeightHistoryID int
                            constraint PK_WeightHistory
                            primary key
                            identity (1, 1),
            MeasureValue money,
            MeasureDate date,
            MeasureTime time(0),
            PersonID int,

            constraint FK_Weight_Person foreign key (PersonID) references Person.Person (PersonID)
        );
    end;
go
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where lower(name) = N'worktime')
    begin
        create table WorkTime (
            WorkTimeID  int
                        constraint PK_WorkTime primary key
                        identity(1, 1),
            WorkDate date,
            WorkTime time(0),
            PersonID int,
            TimeReferenceID int,

            constraint FK_WorkTime_Person foreign key (PersonID) references Person.Person (PersonID) on delete cascade,
            constraint FK_WorkTime_Reference foreign key (TimeReferenceID) references Work.Timereference (TimeReferenceID)
        );
    end;
go
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where lower(name) = N'timereference')
    begin
        create table Work.TimeReference (
            TimeReferenceID int
                constraint PK_TimeReferene primary key
                identity (1, 1),
            WorkTime time(0),
            WorkTimeStartDate date,
            WorkTimeEndDate date
        );
    end;
```

Comment: Can you just set the default values for the columns?  Then you wouldn't have to worry about specifying each column.

Comment: @Jerrad, thanks for your comment. It works, but it's not what I need, I need to find a way to generate the columns with the values for each table.

Comment: You might look into creating a table that has columns for TableName, ColumnName and DefaultValue.  Populate that table and then you could select the default values out for each column.  You would still have the problem of casting each value to whatever the appropriate data type is, and I'm not sure it would be any neater than what you already have.